# VBA-Excel not responding when using a big range in my vba code

Tags: excel, vba, crash, range

I´m working with the Worksheet_Change event, the range in which the event detects changes is large. When i try to make changes in a cell inside the range excel stops working and shows the message: `Not Responding`, i don´t know if is the size of the range what is making the application to crash or if the code is going into a loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D13:AU91"))
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Desviaciones UB")
    
    Dim wb As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UB-Clase A")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        
        If cell.Value = "N.I.O" Then
        
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Dim NumFila As Long
            NumFila = cell.Row
            
            ws.Rows(lastRow).Copy
            ws.Rows(lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            
            Dim i As Long
            i = 1
            
            Dim BMS As String
            BMS = ""
            
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = lastRow - 3
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "TPM"
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = "KW" & NumSemana
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = wb.Cells(NumFila, 3)
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 14).Value = "Portavoz"
            
            Do While BMS = ""
                BMS = Cells(NumFila - i, 2)
            Loop
            
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = BMS
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next
         
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to disable events at the start and re-enable them at the end. `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: Do you expect there to be more than one with a value of "N.I.O"? If no, then consider using `exit for`

Comment: The application still doesn´t  respond

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad no, is just one cell at the time that will change it´s value to N.I.O, could you explain a little bit more about the 'exit for' and how can i use it in my code ?

Comment: `Do While BMS = ""`, `BMS = Cells(NumFila - i, 2)`, `Loop` is likely the culprit. What worksheet are  you trying to reference here? In other words, which worksheet is `Cells` on?

Comment: @Warcupine - from the looks of it, OP is modifying another sheet, not the sheet containing this hander.

Comment: Add `Exit for` just before the `end if`. This will cause the loop to end once the one cell has been found and processed

Comment: @BigBen Yeah, looks like it, still should probably be there though. the BMS loop definitely goes infinite if that first (only) cell it checks is empty.

Comment: @BigBen the 'Worksheet_change' event is in the worksheet "UB-Clase A", 'Cells' is in this same Worksheet, when it detects a cell in the range 'rng' it makes changes in another sheet, the one called "Desviaciones UB".

Comment: Ok. Well your `Do While` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `i = i + 1` before `Loop`

Comment: thanks, i just realize i didn't increase the counter

Comment: What is the intention of `BMS`? Are you trying to find the last value in column B?